# How can I keep my mails on my PC, but delete from the server regularly?

Tags: email, backup, thunderbird, email-client

I want to keep all the mails on my PC, but want to delete all the mails which are 10 or more days old. I am using Thunderbird as my mail client. Is there any option to do that? Please help guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is exactly what the POP3 protocol does. Connect to your mail server with POP3 and then set it to download messages and delete them from the server after so many days. This is exactly the opposite direction of where most people have gone and are going. Nobody wants their email, contacts, appts., etc. stuck on their computer and lost when the hard drive crashes. That’s why it’s all synced in the cloud now and accessible on any device.

Comment: @Appleoddity you should post this as an answer...

Comment: @Appleoddity thanks for the clarification. I'll try according to your advice. But agtoever is right, you should reply this as answer.

Comment: This supposes that his email server supports POP3 which isn't known, and IMAP seems to be taking over.